# Combinations (Again)

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, combinations, permutation

I am pretty newbie in programming except for some functional programming and math algorithm implementations. Anyway I started an online programming course and come to this question. Given integer A and B
return all possible combinations of B elements in array [1,..,A]  in alphabetical order (*i.e* [[1,...,B] , [1,...B-1,B+1], [1,..,B-1,A],...])). Now I am aware of the library itertools and I have seen some solutions, however I wanted to solve it myself, since a friend told me that it is done with recursion.

```
def combinations(A,B):
# Three ideas:

# Combination using recursion should look as follows:
# combinations[1,2,3,4,5]
#          = [[[1] + combinations[2,3,4,5]], 
#            [[2] + combinations[3,4,5]]...].
# Terminating condition combination[x] = [x]

# Another idea: print all binary permutations
# with fixed B numbers of ones. Binary combin-
# ations (1,0,0) for A = 3, B = 1 are [(1,0,0),
# (0,1,0), (0,0,1)] Cartesian product of these
# with [1,2,3] would give [1] [2] [3] after rem-
# oving zeroes. In this cas the recursion should
# look as follows: perm([1,0,0]) = [[1, perm([0,
# 0])], [0, perm([1,0])]] In this case terminat-   
# ing condition should looks as : perm(x) = x.

# Simplest idea: for element A, either add to
# some array in helper or not. helper(A,B) if value is A appended
# helper(A-1,B-1) and append B-1 values, if A value is not appended
# helper(A-1,B) until now append A or when A==B 
# append A and B till array filled. B == 0 helper.append([])

array = [[]]
def helper(array,A,B):

    if not B:
        array.append([])
        # return ??
    for i in range(0,1):
        if i or A == B: # A == B means add elements until B empty.
            array[-1].append(A)
             #something helper(A-1,B-1)
            return # ?? return 
        else:
            #something helper(A-1,B)
            return # ?? return #don't append value A to array
    return array
array = helper(array,A,B)
```

Can someone at least explain how to implement the "simple" solution? I really like the idea, and want to understand how to implement my own recursions. Thanks!

Comment: Wrong forum - we care about broken code with sepcific problems and specifi answers. Not about giving tutorials or explaining basic code. Read [How to debug small programs (#1)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and debug the code until you groke it. Please go over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) again and if you have questions provide 
your code as [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It's worth noting that the documentation for [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) contains python code that does the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can someone at least explain how to implement the "simple" solution?

'Simple' is subjective but I find the following implementation of `combinations` easy to reason with. Continuation-passing style enables a wishful thinking where we can write something like this

```
combinations (some_list, lambda result: print (result))
# some output ...
```

where `result` is the ordered combinations produced from `some_list`. Using this style, we can write the program similarly to how you imagine it working

```
# combinations [1,2,3,4,5]
# = [ [1] + combinations[2,3,4,5] ]
#   , [2] + combinations[3,4,5]
#   , ...
#   ]

def combinations (l, cont = ???):
  ???
  head, *tail = l
  return combinations (tail, lambda result:
                               cont ([ [ head ] + r for r in result ] + result))
```

We add a conditional to ensure that we don't destructure an empty list, `l`. This is the base case in which we return the empty result `[ [] ]` – changes in **bold**

```
def combinations (l, cont = ???):
  if not l:
    return cont ([ [] ])
  else:
    head, *tail = l
    return combinations (tail, lambda result:
                                 cont ([ [ head ] + r for r in result
```

Lastly, add a default continuation `cont = identity` so our function can be *used* in direct style or continuation passing style – changes in **bold**

```
def identity (x):
  return x

def combinations (l, cont = identity):
  if not l:
    return cont ([ [] ])
  else:
    head, *tail = l
    return combinations (tail, lambda result:
                                 cont ([ [ head ] + r for r in result ] + result))
```

Here it is altogether now

```
def identity (x):
  return x

def combinations (l, cont = identity):
  if not l:
    return cont ([ [] ])
  else:
    head, *tail = l
    return combinations (tail, lambda result:
                                 cont ([ [ head ] + r for r in result ] + result))


print (combinations (range (0)))
# [[]]

print (combinations (range (1)))
# [[0, []]

print (combinations (range (2)))
# [[0, 1], [0], [1], []]

print (combinations (range (3)))
# [[0, 1, 2], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0], [1, 2], [1], [2], []]
```

We call `print (combinations (list))` above, but because we defined our function using continuation-passing style, we can also call it from the outside using a continuation, ie `combinations (list, print)`

```
combinations (range (4), print)
# [ [0, 1, 2, 3]
# , [0, 1, 2]
# , [0, 1, 3]
# , [0, 1]
# , [0, 2, 3]
# , [0, 2]
# , [0, 3]
# , [0]
# , [1, 2, 3]
# , [1, 2]
# , [1, 3]
# , [1]
# , [2, 3]
# , [2]
# , [3]
# , []
# ]

print (combinations (range (4), len))
# 16
```

Comment: as a functional programmer, i think you will enjoy this answer. as a python programmer, i think you will find that the python community favours a more imperative approach.

Comment: Wow, I find mind blowing that it works.  Thank you. I know the question you solved. I wanted to move to this question after previous, which just asks for all combinations with fixed length.
Something like

    list(filter(lambda: x: len(x) == 2, combinations(range(4), cont = identity))) ??

I called the last simplest because I actually had it working except it gave me some elements maany times. Thank you again :)